# Rails background thread for sqs polling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, amazon-sqs, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I want to write a background running thread/worker, which will poll messages from SQS and will assign messages to worker threads to process.

The background polling process should start at service startup. Also, I want to start multiple background worker threads for some rails services.

(fyi, I have already tried shoryuken, and it seems very slow to my use-case so I am writing my own poller)

Please suggest some guidelines/code snippets/tips on how to create such a poller.

Requirements :

1. Background running worker thread starts up on service startup.
2. Worker thread does not impact service from processing HTTP requests on its other APIs.
3. There might be a need to start multiple poller threads as well(Reason for multiple sqs queues it's better to have multiple poller threads otherwise single poller will get stuck 'long polling' on empty queues).
4. These worker threads may be initialized within the rails app or there can be a separate process for it. In case of separate process I will do POST to localhost Rails API endpoint to process message.

I am looking for help for ruby / rails points of view as I am new to it. Though I understand SQS working so not much is required for SQS specific code. Just a background worker process doing something meaningful will do.

Thanks, any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Based on our requirements, I believe you will end up writing your own version of shoryuken, as it implements all requirements you need. Could you give me more details on why shoryuken is slow for you? Maybe you can change some configuration to make it faster, for example setting the delay to 0.

Comment: As I understand, shooryuken is slow because poller thread is same for all the queues. Let's says I have two queues one with high traffic and one with very low traffic. Then poller thread will wait on low traffic queue for 20 secs(ReceiveMessageWaitTime) before proceeding on to high traffic queue. This will cause backlog to get created during that period fir the HT queue. Though ReceiveMessageWaitTime is configurable, I want it to be set to 20 secs for all the queues. Let me know if I understood shoryuken incorrectly.

Comment: The poller is the same for all queues, but the `ReceiveMessageWaitTime` is configurable (https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken#configuration), you can change it to the value you want (which by default is 0 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html). The idea of Shoryuken is to load balance the queues consumption using a single process. Based on my tests, having multiple pollers, make it much more complex, not only code wise, also on the memory allocation side etc and does not give much benefits to load balancing in the way Shoryuken does.

Comment: having a single poller for multiple queues is a major disadvantage for us.  This either results in starving out some queues as poller is busy long polling other queue and too frequent polls if RMWT set to 0. To solve this I created another library with separate polling threadpools for each queue.